# Asp.Net Core: Debug -Attach to process is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging

The way we are used to debug a running "IISExpress" process in .Net Framework is by attaching a process by the name "iisexpress.exe" in Visual Studio. But attaching the iisexpress process is not working in .Net core. It shows the message - "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806765/to-which-process-should-i-attach-visual-studio-debugger-to-debug-a-kestrel-appli

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To debug a running iisexpress instance in .Net core, you will have to attach "dotnet.exe" process in Visual Studio.
*Update - 1: If dotnet.exe does not work for you, check "{projectName}.exe" as well.
*Update -2: Attaching "iisexpress.exe" works with .net 5

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer later. Have a nice day.

Comment: I think this is not working for .Net Core 3.0+ projects. Attaching to "dotnet.exe" process(es) gives me a warning message on the breakpoint. Attaching to the <projectName>.exe does the job.

Comment: For my case dotnet.exe required for outofprocess. No needed for inprocess hosting(w3wp.exe is enough)

Answer (score 17):

In Visual Studio 2019 using "dotnet watch run" I could no longer attach to the "dotnet.exe" process, I would get the Symbols could not be loaded error, took me a while to figure out but instead I attached to [project name].exe which is in the list of running processes and I could successfully attach the debugger to a process with symbols loaded and debug.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using Asp.Net Core 2.2 with `InProcess` Hosting Model, the accepted answer doesn't work. But, I should choose from the menu `Debug` > `Attach to process`, then select the **"Show processes from all users"** checkbox (below the list of process) and select **"iisexpress.exe"**. It works properly and hit the break points.

Answer (score 1):

> Visual studio does not loads all dlls (don't know why). Try this:

1) First attach with w3wp.exe (for InProcess Hosting) or dotnet.exe (for OutOfProcess Hosting)

2) Load Symbols manually:

Go to Debug > Windows > Modules (or try shortcut Ctrl + Alt + U)

Search and select dll (and dependent dll's) which you want to debug and right click > Load Symbols.