# F5 does not launch application until an endpoint is called

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, netcoreapp2.1

Consider the following:

- console application in `netcoreapp2.1` that is set up to load some NuGet packages and place them in a folder within the project. Upon completion, application stops
- After upgrading the application to `net6.0`, the NuGet pckages are only loaded after making an HTTP request to any endpoint in the app

More specifically, I hit F5 to launch the application in Debug mode:

- `netcoreapp2.1` does what it is supposed to, and then debug stops
- `net6.0` does not start application until HTTP request is sent from browser
- the process name is different between the applications

[image]

Trying to find what could be causing this, I came across [this post](https://dailydotnettips.com/back-to-basic-difference-between-start-debugging-start-without-debugging-in-visual-studio/) that lists an expected flow of actions when we hit F5:

1. VS will load all required symbols
2. Then, it will attach the debugger to a process
3. Then, it will launch the application

It seems like my `net6.0` does not hit step 1 until I make a call to an endpoint, but I am not sure how to move forward, or what to look for.

I'm very new to development in general, and often can't find the proper terms to use when searching for a problem, so any advice you can give search-wise is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After seeing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297776/12080599) in another post, I realized I was debugging using the wrong profile. After selecting the project one (or using process `{project name}.exe`), the application behaved as expected.

### launchSettings.json -> profiles

Before:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

After:

```
"profiles": {
    "Project Name": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "hotReloadEnabled": false
    }
  }
```